# Compare keys in two YAML files and print differences?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If we have two yaml files how would we compare keys and print mismatched and/or missing keys?
I tried DeepDiff but it takes dictionaries, iterables, etc, how would I convert yaml files to dictionary and use DeepDiff or any other method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
import yaml
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

def yaml_as_dict(my_file):
    my_dict = {}
    with open(my_file, 'r') as fp:
        docs = yaml.safe_load_all(fp)
        for doc in docs:
            for key, value in doc.items():
                my_dict[key] = value
    return my_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = yaml_as_dict(yaml_file1)
    b = yaml_as_dict(yaml_file2)
    ddiff = DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True)
    print(ddiff)
```

Comment: DeepDiff compares YAML files, without the need to convert them to dictionaries, so you could simplify your code to avoid that unnecessary step, and compare YAML files in its original format

Answer (score 2):

Try out this package [deepdiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff).I had a similar usecase and found it very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) To convert to flattened `dict`, then compare.

Answer (score 1):

To load a yaml file as a dictionary you can use PyYAML:

```
import yaml

with open("example.yaml", 'r') as fp:
    d = yaml.safe_load(fp)
```